# UploadableFilePath field in entity definition is ignored (uploadable doctrine extensions)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, doctrine-extensions, doctrine-uploadable

### Summary

My problem is connected with the fact that the entity field marked with `@Gedmo\UploadableFilePath` annotation is ignored by Symfony3.  I am using the [Uploadable behavior extension for Doctrine2](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md).

### CODE

In my entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column
 * @Gedmo\UploadableFileName
 */
private $name;

/*
 * @ORM\Column
 * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
 */
 private $path;
```

### SYMPTOMS

At first, I have noticed though that the `path` column is not generated in MySQL.

Then I found out that whenever I delete `name` field I get the following error:

> [Gedmo\Exception\InvalidMappingException]   Class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\plik" must have an UploadableFilePath or Uploadable 
>   FileName field.

### Documentation

In `doctrine-uploadable` documentation I see that:

> @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\UploadableFilePath: This annotation is used
>   to set which field will receive the path to the file. The field MUST
>   be of type "string". Either this one or UploadableFileName annotation
>   is REQUIRED to be set.

so it seems that I should be able to set `$path` field only.

### Help request

Please advice why is `UploadableFilePath` field not being generated and why can't I delete the `$name` field?

Comment: Not sure what's happening here but do you have the `name` and `path` columns in your database table?  Have you specified them as `string` columns?  Have you configured the path as required by the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have made a simple typo. There was lack of one `*` in the comment line.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column
 * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
 */
 private $path;
```

It seems that symfony ignores annotations in such a case.